# boolean input to setState from mapped data

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript, object, state

I've got this `.map` to map a list of checkboxes.
I'd like to map the `setState` as well, and make in sort it dynamically points out the value binded to each `column` object:

```js
    const [activeColumns, setActiveColumns] = useState<any>({
        creationDate: false,
        destination: false,
    })

    const columns = [
        { label: 'Creation_date', value: "creationDate" },
        { label: "Destination", value: "destination" }
    ]

    return (
        // ...
    {
        columns.map((column: any, index: number) => (
            <MenuItem onClick={() => setActiveColumns({...activeColumns, [column.value]: !activeColumns[column.value]})}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <FormControlLabel control={<Checkbox checked={activeColumns[column.value]}/>} label={column.label} />
                </FormGroup>
            </MenuItem>
       ))
   })
```

I don't know how to dynamically point to `activeColmumns` keys from `columns` values.
I'm using **React TS** and **MUI**

Comment: Why is `activeColumns` a single object instead of an array?

Comment: to keep things simple in the first place - if needed, it doesn't have to stay that way, though

Comment: It's called `activeColumns` plural so I guess more than one column can be active. Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes, you're right! It's there to show/hide columns within a dataTable component using checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as intended, just wrap your expression with `JSX fragments` or any parent element

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormGroup from "@mui/material/FormGroup";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { MenuItem } from "@mui/material";

export default function CheckboxLabels() {
  const [activeColumns, setActiveColumns] = useState<any>({
    creationDate: false,
    destination: false
  });

  const columns = [
    { label: "Creation_date", value: "creationDate" },
    { label: "Destination", value: "destination" }
  ];

  return (
    // ...
    <>
      {columns.map((column: any, index: number) => (
        <MenuItem
         key={column.value}
          onClick={() =>
            setActiveColumns({
              ...activeColumns,
              [column.value]: !activeColumns[column.value]
            })
          }
        >
          <FormGroup>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox checked={activeColumns[column.value]} />}
              label={column.label}
            />
          </FormGroup>
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```